# Python error, "NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions"

Tags: python, numpy

I'm kinda new to python, currently working on a project and getting this error with this lines of code.

```py
    g1_coll[obstacle==0]=tau*(g1+g2-g3+g4)
    g2_coll[obstacle==0]=tau*(g1+g2+g3-g4)
    g3_coll[obstacle==0]=tau*(-g1+g2+g3+g4)
    g4_coll[obstacle==0]=tau*(g1-g2+g3+g4)
```

can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: You should provide the structure of the variable `g1_coll` and `obstacle` to make the question more understandable

Comment: lang indentifer added

Comment: @Nikaido the problem relies on "obstacle", it is a matrix (400,600), the thing is that i nedd to make g1_coll 0 obstacle is 0, i thought of making a while cicle or an if statement but not sure if it works the same way as in matlab that i'm more familiar to

Comment: please, add the structure of g1, g2, etc. Otherwise any answer attempt will be just  speculation. For now, it's -1 because is not informative for the community

Answer (score 9):

I Assume the error you are getting is because all of your arrays are 2-dimensional. I suggest you try using `numpy.putmask(matrix, mask, new_matrix_values)`

For instance

```
    mask = (obstacle == 0)
    numpy.putmask(g1_coll, mask, tau*(g1+g2-g3+g4))
    numpy.putmask(g2_coll, mask, tau*(g1+g2+g3-g4))
    numpy.putmask(g3_coll, mask, tau*(-g1+g2+g3+g4))
    numpy.putmask(g4_coll, mask, tau*(g1-g2+g3+g4))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should probably work as well

```
mask = (obstacle == 0)
new_array = tau*(g1+g2-g3+g4)
g1_coll[mask]= new_array[mask]
```

Notice the last `[mask]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers are mentioning to the source of the problem (e.g., [melqkiades answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61485863/13394817)). I try to reproduce the problem in another way inspiring from [this post](https://github.com/roamanalytics/mittens/issues/6).

So, such a mistake will be happened if we use [`np.matrix`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) (which is 2D - it is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future) instead of `np.array`, that I tried to explain in the following code:

```
# Note that using np.array instead of np.matrix will get a 1D array with shape --> (4,)    ==1D==> 1D res is expected
g_coll = np.matrix([0.94140464, 0.96913727, 0.43559733, 0.45494222])   # shape --> (1, 4)  ==2D==> 2D res may be expected wrongly
# [[0.94140464 0.96913727 0.43559733 0.45494222]]

my_boolean_array = g_coll < 0.5                                        # shape --> (1, 4)
# [[False False  True  True]]

# g_coll[my_boolean_array]                                             # shape --> (1, 2)
# [[0.43559733 0.45494222]]

# The point is here, where we are expecting res to be 2D, wrongly, because g_coll[my_boolean_array] is in 2D, but that must be 1D
res = np.array([[0, 0]])                            # shape --> (1, 2)
g_coll[my_boolean_array] = res                      # --> res must be 1D: np.array([0, 0])

# The true answer will be as:
# res = np.array([0, 0])                            # 1D --> shape: (2,)
# g_coll[my_boolean_array] = res
# # [[0.94140464 0.96913727 0.         0.        ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what you are assigning using the mask. Not knowing what's inside g1, g2, g3 and g4 it's quite difficult to understand what you are doing, but probably

```
tau*(g1+g2-g3+g4)
```

is a vector of two dimension. Instead you need to assign a single value. For example, if you change your assignment in this way, it will probably work:

```
g1_coll[obstacle==0]=(tau*(g1+g2-g3+g4))[0]
g2_coll[obstacle==0]=(tau*(g1+g2+g3-g4))[0]
g3_coll[obstacle==0]=(tau*(-g1+g2+g3+g4))[0]
g4_coll[obstacle==0]=(tau*(g1-g2+g3+g4))[0]
```

or, if it is not working:

```
g1_coll[obstacle==0]=(tau*(g1+g2-g3+g4))[0][0]
g2_coll[obstacle==0]=(tau*(g1+g2+g3-g4))[0][0]
g3_coll[obstacle==0]=(tau*(-g1+g2+g3+g4))[0][0]
g4_coll[obstacle==0]=(tau*(g1-g2+g3+g4))[0][0]
```

But before doing anything you should understand what's inside your input (`tau*(g1+g2-g3+g4)`).

**My guess is that probably g1, g2, g3, and g4 are vectors of two dimensions**

With this example I can reproduce your error:

```
import numpy as np
import random


my_matrix = np.random.rand(4)
print(my_matrix)

my_boolean_array = my_matrix < 0.5
print(my_boolean_array)

my_matrix[my_boolean_array] = [[0, 0]] # two dimensions array! not a single value. This will not work
print(my_matrix)
```

Try to print the value inside

```
print(tau*(g1+g2-g3+g4))
```